# how to call javascript confirmation dialog box before pageload event in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, .net

This is my server side code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
       {

               string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
               if (confirmValue == "Yes")
                {
                UserId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["UserId"]);
                ProgramSrNno =          Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ProgramSrNo"]);
                UpdateAcknowledment(UserId, ProgramSrNno);
            }
        }
   }
```

This is my javascript code:

```
window.onload = Confirm();

function Confirm() {
       var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
       confirm_value.type = "hidden";
        confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
        if (confirm("Do you want to Acknowledge?")) {
            confirm_value.value = "Yes";
        } else {
            confirm_value.value = "No";
        }
        document.forms["frmAcknowledgement"].appendChild(confirm_value);

    }
```

i want dialog box should come first then accordingly code behind pageload event work. if user has selected ok then pageload code should work else not.
but here first my code behind  pageload event is running then it is going to javascript code.

Comment: i tried this also:  protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript:Confirm(); ", true);
    } but it is just attaching that script it is not giving dialog box. 1st init event code ran then pageload code ran then javascrip code

Answer (score 0):

Please check this one

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Confirm", "if(confirm('Are you sure?')){alert('ok');}else{alert('cancel');}", true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi, this is also not giving pop up dialog box for confirmation. 1st preinit code ran but didnt gv dialog box then pageload code ran.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

`PageLoad` is handled at the server, a javascript `confirm()` is executed on the client *after* the pageload has been executed.

But you can let the javascript post back to the server again. If you put a hiddenfield control in the page and set its value in your javascript, you can retrieve the value of the field during postback

**markup**

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidField" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
```

**JS**

```
function Confirm() {
    if (confirm("Do you want to Acknowledge?")) {
        document.getElementById('hidField').value = "Yes";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('hidField').value = "No";
    }
    document.forms[0].submit();
}
```

**codebehind**

```
if(Page.IsPostBack) 
{
    string confirmValue = this.hidField.Value;
}
```